# SQLITE "no such column" if created by "AS"

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, dynamic-columns

I'm creating a temporary column in SELECT-clause like this:

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN a THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS my_col 
FROM foo
```

Now i can access and order the result by using "my_col", i.e.

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN a THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS my_col 
FROM foo 
ORDER BY my_col
```

But when I want so extend the columns like

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN a THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS my_col, 
       my_col * 5 AS my_col_2 
FROM foo
```

SQLite produces "no such column: my_col".

So how can I use a temporary column for further usages in query? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a sub-query:

```
SELECT X.my_col, X.my_col * 5 AS my_col_2
FROM (
     SELECT *, CASE WHEN a THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS my_col FROM foo
     ) X
ORDER BY X.my_col
```

Or just repeat the case statement:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN a THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS my_col, CASE WHEN a THEN 1 ELSE 0 END * 5 AS my_col_2 FROM fo
```

Comment: I hoped to use the column to avoid repeating the statement. A subquery doesn't work also, because in your example my_col_2 (the temporary column) isn't used. But I read, that it's impossible to use virtual columns in SELECT. They are only usable in WHERE and ORDER.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by creating a view:

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS foo_view SELECT *, CASE WHEN a THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS my_col FROM foo
```

after that I can access the view containing the new column as I wished

```
SELECT *, my_col FROM foo_view
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN a THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS my_col, CASE WHEN a THEN 1 ELSE 0 END * 5 AS my_col_2 FROM foo
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick Answer. Sure that works, but that's just the way I didn't want to take (because in my App, the condition is very big, and I don't want to include it twice).

Comment: then probably the best option is to have it in a sub-query or if you have multiple queries with the same CASE maybe you can create a view to simplify your life

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot use an alias at the exact moment you are declaring it:

```
-- this works
select col c        
from Table1
order by c;

-- this works
select col c
from Table1
where c = 1;

-- this won't
select col c,
       c * 2
from Table1
order by c;
```

You can play with those in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e2a8c5/6).